# Create Unique LicenseIDs and Password for each loop

Tags: php, sql, forms, loops, for-loop

I'm currently making a webpage where the admin on the page can generate a specific amount of new users (depending on the order). Right now the function to add new users, 1-many, is working. Although when I create new members, they do not have unique "random"-licenses. All the users that are created under the same generate have the same.

**admin.php** (the code with the form and functions)

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">

  <title>Generera licenser</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" charset="ISO-8859-1" />



</head>



<?php
include('template.php');
if(isset($_POST['email']))            //inkluderar template och hämtar inlogg//
{
$characters = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

function genRandomString($length = 10) {
    $characters ='0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
    $string = '';
    for ($p = 0; $p < $length; $p++) {
    $string .= $characters[mt_rand(0, strlen($characters))];        //funktion för slumpmässig kod//
    }
    return $string;
}
  $courseID = '1';
  $antal = $_POST['antal'];
  $role = '3'; //Detta gör att användaren som skapas får rollvärdet 3//*
  $password = genRandomString();//genererar slumpmässig kod för licens och lösenord//
  $licenseID = genRandomString();



mysql_query('SET character_set_results=utf8');
mysql_query('SET names=utf8');
mysql_query('SET character_set_client=utf8');
mysql_query('SET character_set_connection=utf8');       //dessa löser åäö inmatningar till databasen.(Kan vara redundanta).
mysql_query('SET character_set_results=utf8');
mysql_query('SET collation_connection=utf8_swedish_ci');

for( $tmp = 1; $tmp <= $antal; $tmp++){
    $query = <<<END

    INSERT INTO user(email, company, courseID, password, licenseID, role)   
    VALUES('{$_POST['email']}','{$_POST['company']}', '$courseID', '$password','$licenseID', '$role');  


END;

      //För in data från formuläret till databasen via poster.//

    $mysqli->query($query) or die(mysql_error());
}
header('Location:Bekraftat.php'); //När genereringen är genomförd skickas man till en bekräftelse sida.

}
 $content = <<<END
 <div class="row">
         <div class="container">
         <div class="jumbotronadmin">
            <div class="jumbotron">

          <div class="container">

  <h2>Generera licenser</h2>




            <form action="admin.php" method="post">

              <div class="form-group">

              <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" name="email" placeholder="Email" maxlength="40" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$" title="Ej en legitim emailadress" required>
              </div>
               <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" name="company" placeholder="Företag" maxlength="40" patter="[A-Za-z0-9]+$" required>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" name="antal" placeholder="Antal licenser" maxlength="3" pattern="[0-9]+$" title="OBS! Endast siffror" required>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" name="courseID"><p>Webbutbildningen i brandskyddskunskap</p>
                    </label>
                </div>


                </div>
                <br>

              <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Generera"> 



              </form>
            </div><!-- Stänger jumbotronen --> 
            </div><!-- Stänger jumbotronadmin -->
         </div><!-- Stänger container --> 
      </div><!-- Stänger row --> 
END;

    //innehållet på admin.php med formulär//

  echo $navigation_admin;
  echo $content;
  echo $header;
    // hämtar navigationsmenyn för admin, innehåll och logotyper.//
  ?>
```

So, my question, do you have any idea how to make a loop that creates unique licenses and passwords?

Comment: Regenerate the random strings (`$password` and `$licenseID`) inside the loop. You only generate it once outside the loop.

Comment: as @SverriM.Olsen say generate inside loop and for more unique try to generate with `md5(time());`.

Comment: @urfusion That will only generate a new value every second. If called multiple times a second you will end up with the same value. It is also not random in any way. For any given UNIX timestamp you can just MD5 them and you will get the hash.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As per the current code,fix is ,You need to call `genRandomString` function inside of your loop.

```
for ($tmp = 1; $tmp <= $antal; $tmp++) {
    $password = genRandomString();
    $licenseID = genRandomString();
    $query = <<<END

    INSERT INTO user(email, company, courseID, password, licenseID, role)   
    VALUES('{$_POST['email']}','{$_POST['company']}', '$courseID', '$password','$licenseID', '$role');  


END;

    //För in data från formuläret till databasen via poster.//

    $mysqli->query($query) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

And if you want a ever non repitive string then try

```
function genRandomString($length = 10) {

    $string = md5(microtime());

    return $string;
}
```

Comment: How does putting the PHP code inside a string fix anything?

Comment: `Microtime` will fix this if running multiple time in a second

Comment: What if the function is run more than once on a particular microsecond? This is not a good solution.

Comment: I am not thinking that this function will execute multiple time in microseconds

Comment: You cannot assume that! There may be multiple PHP processes running at the same time. Sure, it may be very unlikely, but it can happen. And when it does it will be impossible to find out what happened/caused it. Also, your function does not use the `$length` argument. You are really sloppy.